# Using . find with arrays. C++

Tags: c++, arrays

What I want to happen here is whenever `result[0]`(randomly generated letter) is found in `array1`(list of words), the word should move to `array2`.

But when I display `array2`, I get the original words no matter what `result[0]` is. And when I display `found` I get a string of numbers repeated (~4942576). What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

char response;
int letter;
int letter2;
int n;
char  result[8];
size_t found= 0;
string array1[70549];
string array2[70549] ;
string array3[70549] ;
string array4[70549] ;
string array5[70549] ;
string array6[70549] ;
string array7[70549] ;
string array8[70549] ;
string array9[70549] ;
string array10[70549] ;

char test = 'a';
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

int main()
{
pointer:
for (int a =0; a<8; a++)
{
    cout<< "Consonant (c) or vowel(v)?" << endl;
    cin >> response; 
    {
        if ( 'c' == response ) 
        {
            srand (time(0));
            letter =  (rand() %21);
            n ++;

            switch (letter)                     //selects random const
            {
            case 0: 
                cout << "b" << endl;
                result[n] = 'b';
                break;

            case 1: 
                cout << "c" << endl;
                result[n] = 'c';
                break;

            case 2:  
                cout << "d" << endl;
                result[n] = 'd';
                break;

            case 3: 
                cout << "f" << endl;
                result[n] = 'f';
                break;

            case 4:
                cout << "g" << endl;
                result[n] = 'g';
                break;

            case 5: 
                cout << "h"<< endl;
                result[n] = 'h';
                break;

            case 6: 
                cout << "j" << endl;
                result[n] = 'j';
                break;

            case 7: 
                cout << "k" << endl;
                result[n] = 'k';
                break;

            case 8: 
                cout << "l" << endl;
                result[n] = 'l';
                break;

            case 9: 
                cout << "m" << endl;
                result[n] = 'm';
                break;

            case 10: 
                cout << "n" << endl;
                result[n] = 'n';
                break;

            case 11: 
                cout << "p" << endl;
                result[n] = 'p';
                break;

            case 12: 
                cout << "q" << endl;
                result[n] = 'q';
                break;

            case 13: 
                cout << "r" << endl;
                result[n] = 'r';
                break;

            case 14: 
                cout << "s"<< endl;
                result[n] = 's';
                break;

            case 15: 
                cout << "t" << endl;
                result[n] = 't';
                break;

            case 16: 
                cout << "v"<< endl;
                result[n] = 'v';
                break;

            case 17: 
                cout << "w"<< endl;
                result[n] = 'w';
                break;

            case 18: 
                cout << "x" <<endl;
                result[n] = 'x';
                break;

            case 19: 
                cout << "y"<< endl;
                result[n] = 'y';
                break;

            case 20: 
                cout << "z"<< endl;
                result[n] = 'z';
                break;
            }
        }

        else if ('v' == response)
        {
            srand (time(0));
            letter2 = ( rand() %4);
            n++;

            switch (letter2)                                //selects random vowel
            {
            case 0: 
                cout <<  "a"<< endl;
                result[n] = 'a';
                break;

            case 1: 
                cout << "e" <<endl;
                result[n] = 'e';
                break;

            case 2: 
                cout << "i"<< endl;
                result[n] = 'i';
                break;

            case 3: 
                cout << "o"<< endl;
                result[n] = 'o';
                break;

            case 4: 
                cout << "u" << endl;
                result[n] = 'u';

            }   
        }
        else if (  response != 'c' || 'v')
        {
            cout << "Invalid, please choose 'c' or 'v'"<< endl;
            cin >> response;
        }
    }


}

cout<<endl<< "Your letters are";

for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    cout << result[i];
    cout << " ";
}
ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Documents\\words.txt");
if(file.is_open())
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 70549; ++i)
    {
        file >> array1[i];
    }
}

for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
{
    std::size_t found = array1[i].find(result);

    if (found!=std::string::npos)
        cout << array1[i] << ' ';

}

cout << endl << endl<<"Your words are: ";
for (int i =0; i <sizeof(array2[i]); i++)
    cout << array2[i] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of data to store on the stack. You also never store anything in `result[0]`.

Comment: You're `find`ing `result` in each `string` of `array1`, but your question states that you're trying to find `result[0]` in each element of `array1`. Might that be your problem?

Comment: @chris Unless I'm missing something, those arrays are globals and aren't stored on the stack.

Comment: @polkadotcadaver, Oops, that's right. For some reason, I only realized the global part in relation to `result` being initialized at all. In that case, it's a lot to store in the executable.

Comment: @chris it isn't even stored in the executable :) For the ELF solution. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610682/bss-section-in-elf-file

Comment: No, that was a mistake on my part, my code says result[0].

Comment: @polkadotcadaver, That's interesting, thanks.

Comment: @user3105207, Ah, missed the `cin >> response;` part. I was referring to `response[n]`, where `n` is always greater than zero at that point.

Comment: An idea for a more scalable and readable implementation would be to initialise a static vector which maps vector index to a character. vector<char> consonants = {'b', 'c'... etc}. Then your huge switch statement becomes result[n] = characters[letter]. Same for vowels.

Comment: I know my switch statement is bug and ugly but that part works.

Comment: @user3105207 : You could replace both switch-case statements with a simple array or pair of arrays...

Answer (score 0):

I see the following in your code:

```
array1[i].find(result)
```

This tries to find `result` in each word. Here, `result` is declared as `char[8]`, that is, a string. Since your code never stores anything into the first element of the `result` array, it probably represents an empty string, which can be found in any string. This is not what you want! You probably want to find `result[0]` instead.

You also wrote the following in comments:

> No, that was a mistake on my part, my code says result[0]

Your code clearly says `result`, not `result[0]`. Try changing `result` to `result[0]` (or, because of how your other code works, `result[1]`); this will fix some of the problems.

---

In addition, you are trying to fill some arrays here. Arrays don't support this - you should use vectors instead. Then, you can use their `size` method instead of the incorrect `sizeof` operator:

```
std::vector<string> array2;
...
for (int i = 0; i < array2.size(); i++)
    cout << array2[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Ok new question how do I check to see if an array value is empty and if it is, miss out that value?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to your problem, but for the love of god, don't do those horrible switch statements, that's a LOT of duplicated and redundant code. Here's the same functionality:

```
char pickRandomVowel() {
    char vowels[] = "aeiou";
    return vowels[rand() % sizeof(vowels)];
}

char pickRandomConsonant() {
    char consonants[] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvw";
    return consonants[rand() % sizeof(consonants)];
}

int main()
{
    srand (time(0));

    for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++)
    {
        char response;
        cout<< "Consonant (c) or vowel(v)?" << endl;
        cin >> response;

        // keep retrying
        while (response != 'c' && response != 'v')
        {
            cout << "Invalid, please choose 'c' or 'v'" << endl;
            cin >> response;
        }

        char letter;
        if ( 'c' == response ) 
        {
            letter = pickRandomConsonant();
        }    
        else if ('v' == response)
        {
            letter = pickRandomConsonant();
        }

        cout << letter;
        result[n] = letter;
    }

    // etc...
}
```